# not able to Set-AzMarketplaceTerms due to MFA for Azure

Tags: powershell, terraform, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to accept the terms for a VM image-

```
Set-AzMarketplaceTerms  -Publisher "canonical" -Product "0001-com-ubuntu-server-jammy" -Name "22_04-lts-gen2" -Accept
```

But it gives error-

Get-AzMarketplaceTerms : SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. Token acquisition failed for user manojr@cyient.onmicrosoft.com. Ensure that you have
authenticated with a developer tool that supports Azure single sign on.
At C:\Users\mr65302\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.MarketplaceOrdering\2.0.0\custom\Set-AzMarketplaceTerms.ps1:173 char:17

- ...             $termsObj = Get-AzMarketplaceTerms -Name $Name -OfferType ...
- ```
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzMarketplaceTerms_Get], CredentialUnavailableException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.MarketplaceOrdering.Cmdlets.GetAzMarketplaceTerms_Get

Set-AzMarketplaceTerms : The property 'Accepted' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:1 char:1

- Set-AzMarketplaceTerms  -Publisher "canonical" -Product "0001-com-ubu ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-AzMarketplaceTerms], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound,Set-AzMarketplaceTerms
  ```

with same credentials i am able to accept the terms and create the VM in the portal. but it is throwing error as i am trying to deploy from terraform code. it seems to be due to Multi level Authentification.

open to Any suggestions